# SQL Server 2000 - Stored procedure parameter values with a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from within another stored procedure.  What I want to do is SELECT the value of my parameters from a table, however SQL server rejects this.

```
EXEC sp_MyStoredProcedure
                @ipParm01 = (SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE condition1),
                @ipParm02 = (SELECT value2 FROM table2 WHERE condition2),
                @ipParm03 = (SELECT value3 FROM table3 WHERE condition3)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Can this be done, or should I declare a bunch of variables, fill them with the values from the select statements, use them in the EXEC sp?

Thanx guys!!!

Comment: `should I declare a bunch of variables, fill them with the values from the select statements, use them in the EXEC sp?` - Yes :) You might also consider upgrading the RDBMS as well :)

Comment: @StuartLC - Though this isn't something that has been improved in later versions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do is upgrade your RDBMS

Solution

You are possibly looking for something Like

```js
SELECT 
  @ipParm01 = value1 
FROM table1
WHERE condition1

SELECT 
  @ipParm02 = value2 
FROM table2
WHERE condition2

SELECT 
  @ipParm03 = value3 
FROM table3
WHERE condition3
```

And then Do

```js
EXEC sp_MyStoredProcedure @ipParm01, @ipParm02, @ipParm03
```